# Illegal return statement in Angular Service

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm working on Angular sample application for my learning. When I try to get object list from `service.ts` I'm getting error `Illegal return statement`. This is the service method.

```
getItemList() {
    debugger;
    return this.http.get( environment.apiURL + '/Item').toPromise();
}
```

I checked api  manually using browser and it return data.

This is the component.ts where i used to call the service method

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.itemService.getItemList().then(res=>this.itemList =res as Item[]); 
}
```

inside itemlist error showing  `Illegal return statement`.

Comment: could be the `debugger;` giving you troubles? Also, try removing the `as Item[]` from `ngOnInit()`. It's very likely that the return statement cannot be cast back to Item[], which is why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your component:

```
this.itemService.getItemList().then(res=>this.itemList =res as Item[]);
```

You cannot return a statement, but you can write it like these examples instead:

```js
this.itemService.getItemList().then(res => {
  this.itemList = res as Item[];
});

this.itemService.getItemList().then(res => (this.itemList = res as Item[]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i implemented as you said , now in debug mode im getting "res is not defined" and itemList is also undefined .